# Connect a Magic Keyboard to a Windows 10 PC with a Logitech Unifying Receiver?

Tags: keyboard, windows, usb, bluetooth

I hope someone can help me with this. I have a user at work that wants to connect her Apple Magic Keyboard to her Windows 10 work PC (she just likes the way the keys are).

The PCs don’t actually have a Bluetooth radio, they require a USB receiver to use anything with Bluetooth. Is it possible to connect her keyboard with a Logitech Unifying Receiver to her PC?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to connect her keyboard with a Logitech Unifying Receiver to her PC?

No.  The Unifying Receiver is a proprietary Logitech wireless protocol; it is **not** Bluetooth which is what the Magic Keyboard requires.

Per the [Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP734?locale=en_US):

> **System Requirements**
>
> - Bluetooth-enabled Mac computer with OS X v10.11 or later
> - iOS devices running iOS 9.1 or later

While it will likely connect (if you utilize a Bluetooth USB adapter), there’s no guarantee it will work as expected.

Comment: thank you very much